# A corollary to the Wedderburn-Artin theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, division-algebras

Suppose we proved the Wedderburn-Artin theorem, i.e. we have the fact that if S is a semisimple algebra over a field $F$, then
$$
A \cong M_{n_1} (D_1) \times ... \times M_{n_k} (D_k),
$$
where $D_1,...,D_k$ are skew fields. How can we prove now using this theorem that
if $S$ is a simple algebra, then $S \cong M_n(D)$ for some integer $n$ and skew field $D$? My textbook actually says that it is an obvious corollary, however I cannot see the proof by myself.

Comment: Hint: $(z,0)(x,y)=(zx,0)$.

Comment: $M_{n_1}(D_1)$ is a non-trivial ideal in $M_{n_1}(D_1)\times \ldots \times M_{n_k}(D_k)$

Comment: @julien Sorry, but what it gives us?

Comment: It gives us what Prahlad enunciated. Well, more precisely, that $M_{n_1}(D_1)\times \{0\}\times \ldots\times \{0\}$ is a nontrivial  ideal if $k\geq 2$.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan did you mean $M_{n_1}(D_1) \cong M_{n_1}(D_1) \times \{0\} \times ... \times \{0\}$? Sorry, julien already mentioned this.

Comment: @julien Ok, then we indeed have that $S \cong M_{n_1} (D_1)$. But where did we actually used the fact that $S$ is simple?

Comment: @julien Maybe I understand it wrong, we can say that if $S$ is simple then $M_{n_1}(D_1) \times ... \times M_{n_k}(D_k)$ is simple, and so as $M_{n_1}(D_1) \times \{0\} \times ... \times \{0\}$ is a non-trivial (two-sided ?) ideal, then actually $M_{n_2}(D_2),...,M_{n_k}(D_k) = \{0\}$, so $S \cong M_{n_1}(D_1)$. Is it right? We need to say also that the direct product of algebras is an algebra with the multiplication defined componenwise.

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Rather, if $k\geq 2$... contradiction so $k=1$.